# SwiftUI & Unit test fails: Can't add the same store twice when using core data stack

Tags: swift, unit-testing, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-previews

After updating Xcode to 13.4 my core data persistence stack started to fail for SwiftUI previews and Xcode Unit tests.

### Error message:

```
Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134081 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=Can't add the same store twice}, ["NSUnderlyingException": Can't add the same store twice ...
```

### Persistence stack:

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Persistence")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()

        description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
        description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true

        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.append(description)
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}
```

### Usage for SwiftUI previews:

```
struct MyScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyScreen()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

### Extension to support SwiftUI preview:

```
extension PersistenceController {
    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        // Pre-fill core data with required information for preview.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mistake in your code, when you append to the array of descriptions you now have 2 descriptions.

Change it to:

```
let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!
description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true

// Load
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed, that after loading persistence storage error generated. This error (**Can't add the same store twice**), can be ignored for SwiftUI previews and Unit Tests.

To ignore this type of error needs to check **XCTestSessionIdentifier** and **XCODE_RUNNING_FOR_PREVIEWS** in the process info.

```
if let error = error as NSError? {
    if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCTestSessionIdentifier"] == nil && 
       ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCODE_RUNNING_FOR_PREVIEWS"] == nil {
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```